An error occurred. Using nbformat v5.10.4 and nbconvert v7.16.1 why?
When trying to open a jupyter notebook in GitHub I got this error. Does anyone know why? It happens as well with my own repositories. What should I fix on my end?
Non of the below worked to solve this
uptaded conda
updated jupyter lab
installed latest package of nbconvert

See my comment here.

From my understanding, this was an issue global to all notebooks and users across GitHub.
On my side it is now fixed, maybe give it another try
